# How do I scan a string containing characters and numbers?

Tags: c, authentication, passwords, registration

I'm making my first "big project" in C and I'm currently working on the registration/login part. I would like to make the user insert an efficient password, asking him to insert characters and numbers (I'm not sure if i simply want to print a warning if the inserted password is unsafe or making the user repeat the inserting process but that's not important now). The password will be part of a struct called "user". So, in order to do this, how do i scan an input made of characters and numbers like "hfsk89skh3"??

Comment: If this is a teaching project and you're still using `scanf`, `%s` should do.  (Although your user will then be limited to passwords not containing spaces.)  Or you could use `fgets`, although you'll have to [strip the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776).  If you want to enforce properties of the password (like the length, or the characters it may or may not contain), do that later.

Comment: By *scan*, do you mean using `scanf()` to input the string ("%s" will do), or to you mean examining all characters and count how many for each category (alpha, num, punctuation)?

Comment: It might be helpful not to think of `'0'` thru `'9'` as numbers but as single *digits*. Are you allowed to use library functions in `ctype.h` such as `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` etc? See [character classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/character-classification?view=msvc-160).

Comment: Another possibility -- although for a number of reasons I do not recommend it -- is `scanf(" %[a-zA-Z0-9]")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to check whether a password contains both letters and numbers, I recommend using isaplha() and isdigit()

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main()
{
    char str[] = "12abc12";
 
    int alphabet = 0, number = 0, i;

    //cycle through every character of the string
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
     
        // check for letters (returns 0 if not a letter)
        if (isalpha(str[i]) != 0)
            alphabet++;
 
        // check for decimal digits (returns 0 if not a digit)
        else if (isdigit(str[i]) != 0)
            number++;
    }

//check if you have at least one number and 5 letters 
    if((alphabet>5)&&(number>0)){  
        printf("Valid Password")
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, especially @andrea zaffanella, very useful piece of code bro

Comment: @Tiziano666 No problem! If this was useful to you may you add it as the solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In C a string can contain alphanumeric characters, so if you scan a string and input this value("hfsk89skh3") that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple for loop that iterates over their password and turn on a flag for each condition that you want to check for. Then at the end, if not all of the flags are on, you tell them that the password isn't safe.